# Binding Ctrl+Shift+F

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic, keyboard

I'm trying to bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to one of my quickbar 4 slots but it won't register the key

command. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> works, as does <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

I'm using the Razer Blackwidow ultimate keyboard and naga mouse with the accompanying software. I don't know if that is making a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is a default bind for showing your frame rate (this isn't set anywhere), I'm guessing that this is why it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The game engine has certain hotkeys that cannot be rebound. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> is one as well.